# Error Xcode 5.1 : unknown argument: '-cclib' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

Today, Apple release iOS 7.1. So, I have to download Xcode 5.1 to build on iOS 7.1. In my code has C language. But when I build, I have an error:

```
unknown argument: '-cclib' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
```

Some one tell : **This is a serious problem because several common gcc flags are not supported under clang (most notably -mno-fused-madd)**

So, how can I fix that problem, or I have to wait a fix version from Apple?

Comment: I think, you need to download new command line tool according to your OS version.

Comment: @Mani: I just reinstall Xcode 5.0.2 for my deadline working, so I cannot do your recommend. I will try it later. Anybody try that, download new command line tool ?

Comment: I install new command line but it still fail on linking step

Comment: RESOLVED : I found the answer for this problem. I remove -cclib flag in Build Setting/Other Linker Flag. And no error happen. I think -cclib is not required in clang compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from OP:

**RESOLVED:**

I found the answer for this problem. I **remove -cclib flag in Build Setting/Other Linker Flag**. And no error happen. I think -cclib is not required in clang compiler.

I see some one also have same problem : `unknown argument: -fno-obj-arc' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]`. Please replace -`fno-obj-arc` with `-fno-objc-arc`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing arm64 from my valid architectures in Build Settings.

[image]